# How to catch a li tag that I restore from local storage?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a shopping list. I am using an `ul` tag, appending a `li` tag with JavaScript and saving it in local storage. Now when I restore it I can't catch the restored `li`.

How do I catch it?

```
$("#enter").click(function () {
    if ($("#userInput").val() != "") {
        var input = $("#userInput").val();

        var newBtn = $("<button>X</button>");
        newBtn.click(function () {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });

        var myLi = $("<li></li>");
        myLi.append("<span>" + input + "</span>");
        myLi.append(newBtn);
        myLi.hover(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#76CFE0");
        }, function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#4EB9CD");
        });

        myLi.click(function () {
            myLi.toggleClass("done");
        })

        $("#list").append(myLi);

        $("#userInput").val("");
    } else
        return;
});

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    console.log("intoo")
    // Get
    if (localStorage.getItem("myList") !== null || localStorage.getItem("myList") !== "" ) {
        var myList = (localStorage.getItem("myList"));
        $("#list").html(myList);
        console.log("intoo");
    }
} else {}
```

Comment: You can use `data-attribute` for storing custom information in a html element.
Example: `data-isthatelement = true`

Comment: Is it a requirement to use _local storage_ instead of something else?

Comment: You're never calling `localStorage.setItem("myList", something)`, so there's nothing in storage for that key. Note that you cannot serialize an `HTMLElement`, so store something that allows you to recreate it.

Comment: It's not requied to use local storage if you know something do tell...